# Access index number of a node inside an XML file

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

For a structure such as

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [id] => https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=2/genre=6014/xml
    [title] => iTunes Store: Top Free Applications in Games
    [updated] => 2013-02-04T07:18:54-07:00    
    [icon] => http://itunes.apple.com/favicon.ico
    [entry] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [updated] => 2013-02-04T07:18:54-07:00
                    [id] => https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/whats-word-new-quiz-pics-words/id573511269?mt=8&uo=2
                    [title] => What is the Word? - new quiz with pics and words - RedSpell
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [updated] => 2013-02-04T07:18:54-07:00
                    [id] => https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/temple-run-2/id572395608?mt=8&uo=2
                    [title] => Temple Run 2 - Imangi Studios, LLC
                )
        )

)
```

I'm using the following code to target the `entry` node as each `entry` node stands for a game.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('the path to file');
foreach ($xml->entry as $val)
{                   
   $gameTitle = $val->title;    
   $gameLink = $val->id;
}
```

#### WHAT I'M LOOKING FOR

Target the index of the `entry` node, i.e. `0`, `1`, `2` and so on; i.e.

```
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object // <-- this fella here, capture 0
(
     [updated] => 2013-02-04T07:18:54-07:00
     [id] => https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/whats-word-new-quiz-pics-words/id573511269?mt=8&uo=2
     [title] => What is the Word? - new quiz with pics and words - RedSpell                  
)
[1] => SimpleXMLElement Object // <-- this fella here, capture 1
(
     [updated] => 2013-02-04T07:18:54-07:00
     [id] => https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/temple-run-2/id572395608?mt=8&uo=2
     [title] => Temple Run 2 - Imangi Studios, LLC
)
```

Whatever I do, I just can't seem to get the index of the current node.

### UPDATE

Just for you people to test it out [Code Viper](http://codepad.viper-7.com/aMO4RT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a function called [`iteator_to_array`](http://php.net/iterator_to_array) setting the second parameter to `false`:

```
$entries = iterator_to_array($xml->entry, false);
foreach ($entries as $index => $val)
{
    $gameTitle = $val->title;
    echo "<p>$gameTitle</p><p>Index = $index</p>";

}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8PLFZH). Actually you do not *must* use that function you could also just count:

```
$index = 0;
foreach ($xml->entry as $val)
{
    echo "<p>{$val->title}</p><p>Index = $index</p>";
    $index++;
}
```

By default the `$key` (as in your example code) is the tagname of the XML element. So you can not use it for the index number by default.

Comment: Thanks, but I found an alternate solution for it. +1 though

Comment: @asprin: Please add your alternate solution as an answer as well (yes it's perfectly alright to answer your own questions). I'm also curious how you did it ;)